# GROUP BY - How to create 3 group for the column?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a table of products, fields are id, number_of_product, price
Let's price is min = 100, max = 1000*
How to create 3 groups for this column (PostgreSQL) - 100-400, 400-600, 600-1000*

*PS - it would be nice to know how to split into 3 equal parts.

```
SELECT COUNT(id),
COUNT(number_of_product), 
!!!! price - ?!
FROM Scheme.Table
GROUP BY PRICE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try next query:

```
with p as (
  select 
      *,
      min(price) over() min_price,
      (max(price) over() - min(price) over()) / 3 step
  from products
) select 
    id, product, price,
    case 
        when price < min_price + step then 'low_price'
        when price < min_price + 2 * step then 'mid_price'
        else 'high'
    end as category
from p
order by price;
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql11/b6c0836461eb157b8180e3a7408ecfd5/)

Answer (score 0):

To do this quickly, you can use a case statement to set the groups.

```
CASE WHEN price BETWEEN 100 AND 400 THEN 1 WHEN price BETWEEN 400 AND 600 THEN 2 WHEN price BETWEEN 600 AND 1000 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END
```

You would group on this.

For splitting into equal parts, you would use the NTILE window function to group.

```
NTILE(3) OVER (
    ORDER BY price]
)
```

Comment: Sorry but `NTILE` is not correct https://sqlize.online/sql/psql11/df2c0e1811608893da461fd26621e85d/

Comment: @Slava Rozhnev, could you pls tell what is the correct answer?

Comment: I just edited the answer with the correct NTILE statement

Comment: @SamWare, NTILE can not be used. It assign for 3 groups also all prices are equal.

Comment: @user19021327 I posted my answer

Comment: @Slava Rozhnev, I agree.  However, there are some business cases where NTILE works even though you get the same price in different groups.  Lets say that you loading something in trucks and you want 3 equally weighed trucks.